# Spark Geolocated Points Clustering

Tags: apache-spark, computational-geometry

I have a dataset of points of interest on the maps like the following:

`ID  latitude    longitude
1   48.860294   2.338629
2   48.858093   2.294694
3   48.8581965  2.2937403
4   48.8529717  2.3477134
...`

The goal is to find those clusters of points that are very close to each other (distance less than 100m).
So the output I expect for this dataset would be:

`(2, 3)`

The point 2 and 3 are very close to each other with a distance less than 100m, while the others are far away so they should be ignored.

Since the dataset is huge with all the points of interest in the world, I need to do it with Spark with some parallel processing.
What approach should I take for this case?

Comment: How big is the dataset? Can you get away with a cross join?

Comment: @ss85 the dataset has hundreds of millions of records, with all the points of interest in the world. I would assume a cross join will not be feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved this problem using the following 2 approaches:

**DBSCAN algorithm implemented as Spark job with partitioning**
https://github.com/irvingc/dbscan-on-spark

**GeoSpark with spacial distance join**
https://github.com/DataSystemsLab/GeoSpark

both of them are based on Spark so they work well with large scale of data.
however I found the dbscan-on-spark consumes a lot of memory, so I ended up using the GeoSpark with distance join.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to do a cross join here , however that probably won't work since your data is huge.

One approach is to partition the data per region wise. That means you can change the input data as

```
ID  latitude    longitude latitiude_int longitude_int group_unique_id
1   48.860294   2.338629  48             2             48_2
2   48.858093   2.294694  48             2             48_2
3   48.8581965  2.2937403 48             2             48_2
4   48.8529717  2.3477134 48             2             48_2
```

The assumption here if the integral portion of the lat/long changes that will result > 100m deviation.

Now you can partition the data w.r.t group_unique_id and then do a cross join per partition.

This will probably reduce the workload.